# Does RAID 0 with 2 disks provides four-fold increase in both reading and writing speeds?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid

I've recently come across this blog:

https://support.us.ovhcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006076940-How-to-Configure-Software-RAID-on-Ubuntu-18-04

There is a table with a comparison of different RAID configurations. It is said under the table that speed gain estimates are based on a minimum number of drives in the array.

1) Is this true? My naive intuition hints me that maximum speed gain from two drives in RAID 0 is twofold since instead of reading from a single drive, one would read from both drives simultaneously.

2) Does the theoretical speed gain of RAID 0 linearly scales with number of disks in the array? So for four drives will it be 4x?

Comment: That is correct. (assuming your title was meant to say what question 2 says). Because the data is split across both drives, the speed of data reading and writing increases as more disks are added. It will eventually bottleneck at some point depending on your controller/disk type/etc. But in a perfect world, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that table is wrong is multiple ways.

1) no. Your maximum theoretical speed would be 2x with 2 disks.

2) yes. Theoretically, 4 disks will have 4x read and write speeds on RAID 0. However, drive speeds, interface speeds, file size, and RAID overhead are all factors that will prevent maximum theoretical speed. Not to be ignored, the risk of data loss also goes up linearly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications